# How to split Step definition file in cucumber using selenium Page Object model

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber, pageobjects

I am using Page object model to automate my testing use-cases. Where in I have integrated it with Cucumber.
Now in Cucumber Step definition file I have used:
@Before
-- Here I am initializing driver object
-- and passing this driver object to each of the pages.

@After
-- here I am closing my driver.

In other Glue Code I am writing my logic.

Now the issue I am facing is that when I want to split my Step Definition file into two. There I am facing issue as the second Step Definition files does not have @Before annotation where it does not get driver object.

If I add @Before there in the 2nd one then two instances of driver will be created. which we dont want.
can you help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able to share state between the step definitions files. The idiomatic way to do this in Java is to use dependency injection.

I have written a few blog posts on the topic of sharing state between steps in Cucumber using:

- [PicoContainer](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer)
- [Spring](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/06/24/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-spring)
- [Guice](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/08/16/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-guice)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use one of Dependency Injection module supported by cucumber-jvm to share the WebDriver between the steps. 
https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di

The simplest one is the PicoContainer, and you can find how to configure in this [link](https://cucumber.io/blog/2015/07/08/polymorphic-step-definitions).